# shell script in unix(in bash shell) for copying a file from one location(i.e a directory), to other, without using cp command at all

Tags: linux, unix

Can anyone help me with a shell script in unix(in bash shell) for copying a file from one location(i.e a directory), to other, without using cp command at all(not using it in the script also.Any other command /utility can be used in the script).Can it be really done ? I could'nt find a way out.Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many options do you want?

- rcp
- scp
- dd
- perl
- python
- cat
- while / read / echo

That is nowhere near exhaustive.  You can be creative...have fun!

You could use:

1. `cat` to create a C source file, copy.c
2. `make` or `cc` to compile it
3. And then run it to do the copying.

You could use:

1. cat /usr/bin/cp > x
2. chmod +x x
3. ./x old new

But that is probably cheating.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you can `cat` and redirect the output. Since this sounds like homework, I'll leave it to you to work out the exact syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Erghm. Why?! Anyway...

```
cat file1 > some/other/dir/file2
```

Answer (score 0):

[`install`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?install) is a good one.